# How to pass multiple dropdownlist values to another web pages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, asp.net-webpages

Net Programmers,

I need help to achieve the above.

I have three dropdownlists in one web page and I want to pass all the three values to another web page but I am having errors.

The code is working well with only one dropdown list but I don’t know how to pass all three dropdown lists at once.

I have tried these codes:
On first page (rptMonthFull.aspx)

```
Protected Sub btnChart_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnChart.Click
    Response.Redirect("rptMonthFull-Graph.aspx?" + ddlMonth.Text, ddlYear.Text, ddlProduct.Text)
End Sub
```

On the Second Page (rptMonthFull-Graph.aspx), I have

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ddlMonth.Text = Request.QueryString().ToString()
        ddlYear.Text = Request.QueryString().ToString()
        ddlProduct.Text = Request.QueryString().ToString()
    End Sub
```

But when I use only one of the ddl it will work.

```
Response.Redirect("rptMonthFull-Graph.aspx?" + ddlMonth.Text)
```

This is the error message:

```
'ddlMonth' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value
```

Can someone help me fix the error.
Thanking you in advance.
Lawal5

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect("rptMonthFull-Graph.aspx?ddlMonth=" + ddlMonth.Text +"&ddlYear= " + ddlYear.Text +"&ddlProduct= "+ ddlProduct.Text);
```

in rptMonthFull-Graph.aspx.cs, use below code to retrieve details

```
string ddlMonth= Request.QueryString["ddlMonth"].ToString()
string ddlYear= Request.QueryString["ddlYear"].ToString()
string  ddlProduct.Text = Request.QueryString["ddlProduct"].ToString()
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it meets your requirement